# PHP - save array of objects to a file and reuse it - getting Call to undefined method error

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, store

My first posting here, so pls be patient with me.

I'm currently doing the following: I need to write a guestbook with php. I have a form with which new entries are submitted. An entry is represented by a class:

```
 class entry{
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $text;
    ...
    construct-method and a output() method for html code
    ...
    function getName()
    {return $this->name;}}
```

When the form is submitted, I call the "addToGuestbook.php", where I read out the $_POST[..] and create a new entry:

```
$ent = new entry($name, $email, $text);
```

As I want to store the entry for further use, I put it in an array and save it with help of json:

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents('entries.json'), false);
$entries[] = $ent;
file_put_contents("entries.json",json_encode($entries));
```

After this, I want to manipulate one of the html-pages, so I include a function file and call the function...

```
include "functions.php";
setUpSingleEntries();
```

... in which I iterate over the stored array

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents('entries.json'), false);
foreach($entries as $entry)
{
    if($entry->getName() == $name)
    {
        fwrite($file, $entry->output());
    }
}
```

When I run the whole thing I get a **`Call to undefined method stdClass::getName() in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ex9\functions.php on line 32`** error, **as which line 32 is
    if($entry->getName() == $name)**

I'm pretty done, as I am trying to code the guestbook since a few days and I can't resolve those errors - as well, as I haven't found a solution for this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize an object via JSON, you must first implement the [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface. Assuming you are using PHP 5.4+ (which you should):

```
class Entry implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $text;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'name'  => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'text'  => $this->text
        );
    }
}
```

This will serialize your object as an associative array. However, you cannot unserialize (`json_decode`) directly into this object, so you would need to add some sort of an unserialize method, that will construct the object for you from a `\stdClass`. For example:

```
class Entry implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $text;

    // assuming you have a constructor like this
    public function __construct($name, $email, $text)
    {
        $this->name  = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->text  = $text;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'name'  => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'text'  => $this->text
        );
    }

    public static function fromStdClass(\stdClass $entry)
    {
        // here you can do some validation if $entry actually has these properties

        return new self($entry->name, $entry->email, $entry->text);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the code like this:

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents('entries.json'), false);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $entryObj = Entry::fromStdClass($entry);

    if ($entryObj->getName() == $name) {
        fwrite($file, $entryObj->output());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

json_decode doesn't return objects of type "entry" therefore the error (the object returned doesn't have the getName method defined, it doesn't have the output method either).

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

would ouput

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Your code needs corrections (or make Entry implements JsonSerializable as suggested in other answers):

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents('entries.json'), false);
foreach($entries as $obj)
{
    if($obj->{'name'} == $name)
    {
        fwrite($file, /*Something else*/);// $entry->output() won't work, figure something else out
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Kind regards.